# Prevent Apex Exception Mail

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, error, administration

I have a situation where in our Salesforce org there are a few record triggered flows present for different objects. Currently when a record which triggered the flow fails a validation rule then an exception mail is generated. In the apex exception mail we have our email ids registered.

Is there any way other than removing our email ids from the Apex Exception Mail recipient, we can prevent the emails from getting triggered. In a single day we get inundated with many exception mails from the flow where the root cause is primarily a record failing the validation rule.

Answer (score 1):

There is no documented way to stop flow exception emails but you can limit them to User who last modified the Process or Flow.

This setting can be found in - `Setup -> Process Automation -> Process Automation Settings`

[image]

[More Details](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_troubleshoot_error_email.htm&type=5)

But you should try to correct the validation error to stop the emails altogether.